# Finding all possible combinations of elements of six arrays

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, brute-force, cartesian-product

I have 6 arrays, each has 8 elements. I'd like to write a method that reveals all the possible combinations of all the elements of all arrays like:

```
firstArray firstElement, secondArray firstElement,.... sixthArray firstElement

firstArray secondElement, secondArray firstElement,.... sixthArray firstElement

....etc...

firstArray lastElement, secondArray lastElement,.... sixthArray lastElement
```

How can I do this in the *most efficient* way, the most *performance-friendly* way?

```java
for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < B.length; j++) {
    for (int h = 0; h < C.length; h++) {
      for (int k = 0; k < D.length; k++) {
        for (int l = 0; l < E.length; l++) {
          for (int n = 0; n < F.length; n++) {
            System.out.println(A[i] + " "
                             + B[j] + " "
                             + C[h] + " "
                             + D[k] + " "
                             + E[l] + " "
                             + F[n]);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplest Code would be:

```java
for (first array a) {
  for (second array b) {
    for (third array c) {
      for (fourth array d) {
        for (fifth array e) {
          for (sixth array f) {
            System.out.println(a[], b[], c[], d[], e[], f[]);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is not good performance wise as it will take - no. of arrays * element per array * element per array time.

Answer (score 3):

This is fast becoming an SO FAQ, but for the life of me I can't find the right question that this is a duplicate of, so here's the FPA (frequently provided answer).

Generate all the 6-digit base-8 numbers from 000000 to 777777 in turn.  Each number specifies one of the sets you are looking for: the first digit identifies the element of the first array, the second digit the element of the second array, etc.

That should be enough to get you started, any 'help' I provided in Java would be laughed at.  Whether this is better than the answer you already have (or indeed, materially different from it), I leave you and others to judge.

For your future reference you are trying to compute the *cartesian product* of your 6 arrays.  As to the efficiency of these approaches, well computing the cartesian product of 2 sets each of n elements is O(n^2) and there is no getting around that by clever programming.  So for 6 sets, each of n elements, the computational complexity is going to be O(n^6).